# How to create AWS Windows EC2 and set 2 Web pages to open after EC2 instance is started?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ami

I have a customer requirement where they want to have automated start of Windows instance and have 2 Web pages open by default - automatically.

I know how to create AWS instance using AWS CLI but where to specify to e.g. install Chrome and open 2 web pages (so that they are open and ready once user login to this Win instance).

Comment: Are you looking to do this via CloudFormation?

Comment: I was thinking via AWS CLI if possible but if not - cloud formation is fine..

Comment: Yes, to create EC2 instace. That works. I do not know how to add second part and where to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify commands to run on the first launch of an EC2 instance in the [user data field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html).

If you'd like to specify an EC2 instance's user data script via the AWS CLI, use the `--user-data` parameter [like so](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-api-cli):

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-abcd1234 --count 1 --instance-type m3.medium \
--key-name my-key-pair --subnet-id subnet-abcd1234 --security-group-ids sg-abcd1234 \
--user-data <user data here>
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like Linux way.. how about for Windows EC2? (to open some URL for example)..

Comment: You can specify Powershell commands in an EC2 instance's user data field, so this would look something like `<powershell> Start-Process -FilePath Chrome -ArgumentList <url to open> </powershell>`. See the first link in my answer for Windows examples :)